# How to save the filename as timestamp with D3DXSaveTextureToFileW on C?

Tags: c++, timestamp, filenames

Im having some probolems with C++ .. I'm trying to save a frame with the filename as timestamp but with no success, can anybody help me?

It saves properly if i use:

`D3DXSaveTextureToFileW((LPCWSTR)"file.bmp",D3DXIFF_BMP,tex,NULL);` or

```
D3DXSaveTextureToFileW(L"file.bmp", frameName,D3DXIFF_BMP,tex,NULL);
```

But if I try some more elaborated filename I get some issues, it compiles but doesn't save the file ...

I'm trying to use someting like

```
LPCWSTR frameName;
std::string s = std::string("file") + std::string(".bmp");
frameName = (LPCWSTR)s.c_str();
D3DXSaveTextureToFileW((LPCWSTR)frameName,D3DXIFF_BMP,tex,NULL);
```

Doesn't save ... And If I try something like I want to save the problem continues:

```
time_t seconds;
seconds = time (NULL);      
time_t rawtime;
time ( &rawtime );

LPCWSTR frameName;
std::string s = std::string("file") + std::string(&rawtime);
frameName = (LPCWSTR)s.c_str();

D3DXSaveTextureToFileW((LPCWSTR)frameName,D3DXIFF_BMP,tex,NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast the result of `std::string::c_str()` (a `const char*`) to a `LPCWSTR`. Use a [`std::wstringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to construct the filename:

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::wstringstream frameName;
frameName << L"file" << rawtime << L".bmp";
D3DXSaveTextureToFileW(frameName.str().c_str(),D3DXIFF_BMP,tex,NULL);
```

If you want to store the result of `frameName.str()` use a `std::wstring`.

Comment: Thank you for your time :) Unfortunatelly, it doesnt work due to right operand types .. can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: You need to `#include <sstream>`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply cast a `char*` to a `wchar_t*`. That's not enough. You need to convert the text from being 8 bit encoded to being 16 bit encoded.

That said, since you seem to be using ANSI strings in your program, it may just be easier to use `D3DXSaveTextureToFileA`.

For example:

```
std::string s = std::string("file") + std::string(".bmp");
D3DXSaveTextureToFileA(s.c_str(),D3DXIFF_BMP,tex,NULL);
```

Having said that, if this is meant to be professional software, I'd recommend that you do use UNICODE text throughout your application. In which case you would do it like this:

```
std::wstring s = std::wstring(L"file") + std::wstring(L".bmp");
D3DXSaveTextureToFileW(s.c_str(),D3DXIFF_BMP,tex,NULL);
```